# Extract Items from IEnumerable<ObservableCollection<T>> C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, observablecollection

I have:

```
IEnumerable<ObservableCollection<PointCollection>> rings = 
    from graphic 
    in e.FeatureSet 
    select ((Polygon)e.FeatureSet.Features).Rings;
```

I want to extract all the PointCollection's from each graphic and consolidate them into a single ObservableCollection. Something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<PointCollection> allRings = ?;
```

Is there a better way to iterate this without doing a bunch of nested ForEach statements?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
var allRings = new ObservableCollection<PointCollection>(
    rings.SelectMany(rings => rings)
);
```